# Tesseract couldn't load any languages! java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Tags: tesseract, tess4j

I have upgraded the `tess4j` libraries from 3.4.8 to 4.3.0. Since then I am getting the below error :

> "Error opening data file .src/img/tessdata/eng.traineddata
>   Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory.
>   Failed loading language 'eng'
>   Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
>
> java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

I have already set the environment variable and provided the path to the tessdata directory.

```
String processImage(String imageFileName){
        File imageFile = new File(getImagePath()+imageFileName)
        Tesseract process = new Tesseract() 
        process.setDatapath(".src/img/tessdata");
        //process and extract
        try {
            String outputText = process.doOCR(imageFile)
            //System.out.println("\n"+outputText)
            return outputText
        } catch (TesseractException e) {

            return imageFile.toString()+" Unable to process image file"
        }
    }
```

How can this error be resolved. I have followed many solutions already in Stackoverflow, none seem to work. Any help on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you sure that the pathname ".src/img/tessdata" is correct?  Should it be an absolute pathname?  Should the leading "." be there?

Comment: Oh such silly mistakes! Thanks @StephenC, you are a saviour :) Appreciate it.

Comment: I doubt it *has* to be absolute.  But if you use a relative path you are making the code sensitive to the "current directory" that is in play when you run the app.  (And that could have been the cause of the problem you saw ...)

Comment: Does it always have to be the absolute path? So right now I am giving the entire path in my local machine ie, example - process.setDataPath('C:\Users\CheriyTh\Workspace\ready_api_utils\src\img\tessdata');  in the code

Comment: okay thanks. so if I will have to write this to the repository Readme file to adjust the datapath everytime the code is checked out to a different machine. Thanks